# Cron job for moving directories older than 24 hours

Tags: linux, bash, cron, crontab, cronjob

Well, what I want to do is

1. The cron should run every hour or so
2. It should **move** the
   **directories** in a folder /disk1/data/ older than 24 hours to /disk2/data/
3. The directories moved should contain all the data (files/folders) inside of them

I'm a beginner at cron jobs so I have absolutely no idea where to start. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by the age of a directory? Time since the creation of its inode? I suggest you use `find` to identify the directories you want to move. E.g. like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
res=0
cd /disk1/data/
find -type d -ctime +1 -print0 -prune | \
while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
    if [[ ${i} == */* ]]; then                    # need to ensure subdir exists
        if ! mkdir -p "/disk2/data/${i%/*}; then  # error creating dir?
            res=1
            continue
        fi
    fi
    rm -rf "/disk2/data/${i}"                     # make sure target does not exist
    mv "${i}" "/disk2/data/${i}"                  # move stuff
done
exit ${res}
```

If other people were allowed to write `disk2`, then this code *might* be vulnerable to some kinds of symlink attacks if someone creates the right symlinks fast enough. Not sure.

I suggest you write the script to some file and execute that from the cronjob. You create a conjob with `crontab -e` (make sure you've set your `EDITOR` environment variable appropriately), following the format described in `man crontab`.

Comment: @slhck, nice one, looks good. Although whitespaces other than newlines shouldn't have been a problem with my version either.

Comment: Ah, should have worked, better be safe though :)

Comment: Hey, I'm getting an error when running it,

"read: 13: Illegal option -d"

How do I fix this?

Comment: If the `read` builtin of your bash doesn't support the `-d` option yet, you could omit both the `IFS=` and the `-d ''`, use `-print` instead of `-print0`, and hope that noone in his right mind will use a file name containing a newline character. Now that I think of it, this might be due to the fact that `bash` is executed as `sh` i.e. in compatibility mode. I'll edit the answer, make sure to include the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `-ctime` option of `find` does **not** mean *creation* time but "inode *change* time". The field `st_ctime` is changed by writing or by setting inode information (owner, group, link count, mode, etc.).
For directories, it will also reflect the last time a file (or subdirectory) was created or deleted in that directory.
So, consider whether `find -type d -ctime +1` is really the option you require.